# enviar selección en un spinner

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

estoy haciendo un formulario en android studio y que esa información se me muestre en otra activity pero mi problema es que quiero que se me muestre la selección del spiinner que tengo en el mainactvity se vea en el el activity DatosPersonales en un TextView pero no he podido hacer que se me vea en el otro activity.

codigo del mainactivity

```
btnSiguiente.setOnClickListener {
        var Nombre:String = editTextTextPersonName.text.toString()
        var Apellido:String = editTextTextPersonName2.text.toString()
        var Masculino:String = radioSexMas.text.toString()
        var Femenino:String = radioSexFem.text.toString()
        var fecha:String = txtCalendar.text.toString()
        var Escolari:String = spinner.toString()
        val intent:Intent = Intent(this, DatosPersonales::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Nombre", Nombre)
        intent.putExtra("Apellido", Apellido)
        intent.putExtra("Sexo",Masculino)
        intent.putExtra("Sexo",Femenino)
        intent.putExtra("Fecha",fecha)
        intent.putExtra("Escolaridad", Escolari)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

codigo de DatosPersonales

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos_personales)
    val objetoIntent: Intent=intent
    var Nombre = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Nombre")
    var Apellido = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Apellido")
    txtNombre.text = "Nombre Completo $Nombre $Apellido"
    var SexoM = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Sexo")
    txtSexo.text = "Sexo $SexoM"
    var SexoF = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Sexo")
    txtSexo.text = "Sexo $SexoF"
    var Fecha = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Fecha")
    txtFech.text = "Fecha $Fecha"
    var Escolari = objetoIntent.getStringExtra("Escolaridad")
    txtEscolaridad.text = "Escolaridad $Escolari"
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir alguna captura o algo de lo que se muestra actualmente? Es difícil ayudar sin más información sobre lo que está ocurriendo

Comment: Por favor agrega el código dónde creas el adapter y lo asignas a tu spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estas tomando la seleccion del spinner para pasarla

```
var Escolari:String = spinner.toString()
```

Eso no va asi, va asi:

```
val Escolari:String = spinner.selectedItem.toString()
```

Te faltaba el selectedItem